# Refactoring loop iteration logic into helper function with continue statements

Tags: c++, loops, continue

I have a function that looks (simplified) like the following:

```
void function() {
  // compute n
  int n = ....
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (certain condition is met) {
      if (another condition is met) {
        // do some stuff here
        continue;
      } else if {
        // do some other stuff here
        continue;
      } else {
        // do some other stuff here
      }

      // do stuff here
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to refactor everything in the loop to a helper function, so something like

```
// This function is called within a loop and returns true if current iteration needs to be continued.
bool helper() {
  if (another condition is met) {
    // do some stuff here
    return true;
  } else if {
    // do some other stuff here
    return true;
  } else {
    // do some other stuff here
  }
  return false;
}
void function() {
  // compute n
  int n = ....
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (certain condition is met) {
       if (helper()) {
         continue;
       } 
       // do stuff here
    }
  }
}
```

I was wondering if there's an easier way to write this without having to have the `helper()` return a bool that tells the `function` whether the current loop iteration needs to be continued or not?

Comment: Returning a `bool` seems correct. It looks like `helper()` is actually doing some pre-checking (or `//do stuff here` is doing some post-checking). Would it help you if you named it something more appropriate? Then you'd get `if (!conditions_correct()) continue` or something like that.

Comment: It looks like `function` is pretty massive so splitting it up in separate functions looks like a good idea to me. One note: You don't need the last `else` in any of the versions since it'll continue to the block after the `else` in both versions.

Comment: Looks good to me as well. Without the actual code involved, I think any other optimizations will be hard to call for. (Also to clarify, @TedLyngmo is saying you can keep the code in the `else`, it just doesn't need to be inside an `else` anymore since all other paths do not make it past the `if`/`else if` statements).

Comment: @JohnFilleau Yeah, I would actually name it differently in the actual codebase. I just used simple generic names here in this example

Comment: Why don't you want the helper function to return a boolean? It seems the right way to do it, there may be another ways by having a shared state, you could pass a bool reference to the function for instance, but what with be the goal here?

Answer (score 0):

If I had to rewrite this code, I would probably write it without a helper function:

```
void function()
{
  // compute n
  int n = ....
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
    if (certain condition is _not_ met)
      continue;

    if (another condition is met)
    {
      // do some stuff here
      continue;
    }

    if (yet another condition)
    {
      // do some other stuff here
      continue;
    }

    // do some other stuff here

    // do stuff here
  }
}
```

Notice that there is no `else` necessary after an `if` block that ends with `continue`. This puts all conditions on the same level of importance, including the outer `if` (unless you forgot to show us some common part near the end of the loop that should run unconditionally).

You also see now that there are *two* sequences of "stuff" that are executed if no condition applies that were previously separate. This may indicate a flaw in the logic.